# How to find the first value in a prescribed list?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with multiple records.  For example

```
PERSON, COLOR
John, orange
John, blue
Jack, green
Jack, purple
```

I know I can get min, max, first records using those operations.  Is there a way to get the first value based on an ordered list.  For the given example data above I'd like to get the first value in the order {red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet}.  So the result of the query would be

```
person, color
John, orange
Jack, green
```

Is there some syntax similar to this in standard sql or other specific dialects?

```
select
  person,
  first(color)
from (
  select * from person_color 
  order by color{'red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'})
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person
                                order by case color when 'red' then 1 when 'orange' then 2 when 'yellow' then 3 when 'green' then 4 when 'blue' when 'indigo' then 5 when 'violet' then 6 else 7 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: A better answer than mine, nice

Answer (score 0):

For an example of a dialect specific solution:

MySQL / MariaDB support: `FIND_IN_SET` and `FIELD`.

```
WITH data0 (person, color) AS (
         SELECT 'John', 'orange' UNION
         SELECT 'John', 'blue'   UNION
         SELECT 'Jack', 'green'  UNION
         SELECT 'Jack', 'purple'
     )
   , data1 AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , FIND_IN_SET(color, 'red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet') AS seq
           FROM data0 AS t
     )
   , data AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY seq < 1, seq) AS n
           FROM data1 AS t
     )
SELECT person, color, seq, n
  FROM data
 WHERE n = 1
;
```

and

```
WITH data0 (person, color) AS (
         SELECT 'John', 'orange' UNION
         SELECT 'John', 'blue'   UNION
         SELECT 'Jack', 'green'  UNION
         SELECT 'Jack', 'purple'
     )
   , data1 AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , FIELD(color, 'red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet') AS seq
           FROM data0 AS t
     )
   , data AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY seq < 1, seq) AS n
           FROM data1 AS t
     )
SELECT person, color, seq, n
  FROM data
 WHERE n = 1
;
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+-----+---+
| person | color  | seq | n |
+--------+--------+-----+---+
| Jack   | green  |   4 | 1 |
| John   | orange |   2 | 1 |
+--------+--------+-----+---+
```

[Working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6b1f04c85c16addd80bb163b5d8fed4)

Answer (score 0):

Would the following be of any help?

```
val colors = Seq("red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","violet").zipWithIndex.toDF("name", "rank")
// +------+----+
// |  name|rank|
// +------+----+
// |   red|   0|
// |orange|   1|
// |yellow|   2|
// | green|   3|
// |  blue|   4|
// |indigo|   5|
// |violet|   6|
// +------+----+

val peopleWithColors = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("input.csv")
// +------+------+
// |PERSON| COLOR|
// +------+------+
// |  John|orange|
// |  John|  blue|
// |  Jack| green|
// |  Jack|purple|
// +------+------+

val peopleColorsRanked = peopleWithColors.join(colors).where('color === 'name)
// +------+------+------+----+
// |PERSON| COLOR|  name|rank|
// +------+------+------+----+
// |  John|orange|orange|   1|
// |  Jack| green| green|   3|
// |  John|  blue|  blue|   4|
// +------+------+------+----+
```

And the gist of the solution is to use Windowed Aggregation (over `person` column and sorted).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val byPerson = Window.partitionBy('person).orderBy('rank)
val solution = peopleColorsRanked.withColumn("r", min('rank) over byPerson).where('rank === 'r)
// +------+------+------+----+---+
// |PERSON| COLOR|  name|rank|  r|
// +------+------+------+----+---+
// |  Jack| green| green|   3|  3|
// |  John|orange|orange|   1|  1|
// +------+------+------+----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Gordon's answer. Here is another spark-sql solution using join and row_number.

Input:

```
val df = spark.sql(""" 
select 'John' person, 'orange' color union all 
select 'John', 'blue' union all
select 'Jack', 'green' union all 
select 'Jack', 'purple'
""")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df.show(false)

+------+------+
|person|color |
+------+------+
|John  |orange|
|John  |blue  |
|Jack  |green |
|Jack  |purple|
+------+------+
```

Now use the distinct(person) and explode an array

```
val df2=spark.sql(""" 
with t1 (select distinct(person) person from df )
select person, posexplode(array('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'))  (pos,color)  from t1
""")
df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

+------+---+------+
|person|pos|color |
+------+---+------+
|Jack  |0  |red   |
|Jack  |1  |orange|
|Jack  |2  |yellow|
|Jack  |3  |green |
|Jack  |4  |blue  |
|Jack  |5  |indigo|
|Jack  |6  |violet|
|John  |0  |red   |
|John  |1  |orange|
|John  |2  |yellow|
|John  |3  |green |
|John  |4  |blue  |
|John  |5  |indigo|
|John  |6  |violet|
+------+---+------+
```

Do a join on person and color, assign row_number then filter on it.

```
spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select a.person,a.color, b.pos, row_number() over(partition by a.person order by pos) rw from df a join df2 b on a.person=b.person and a.color=b.color)
select person, color from t1 where rw=1
""").show

+------+------+
|person| color|
+------+------+
|  Jack| green|
|  John|orange|
+------+------+
```